# Durandal / Knockout nested dropdowns in table

Tags: drop-down-menu, knockout.js, nested, durandal

I am pretty new to Durandal and Knockout and I have run into a problem, I cannot figure out how to solve.

I have a view with a table of creditcardlines. Each line have two nested dropdowns named Dimension1Key and Dimension2Key - and they are populated from GetDimensionMatrix ajax call.

The creditlines foreach is populated in a for loop where the two dropdowns are defines as observable - and the data for Dimension2 is computed as a ko.compute.

The table and the dropdowns are initially populated correctly with the correct value selected - but the nesting is not working correctly. No matter which of the Dimension1 drop downs I change, the reference of *self* is to the last row in the table - thus populating Dimension2 of the corresponding Dimension1 with value from the selected value of the last row.
If the Dimension1 value is changed again nothing happens - the reference to the computed function is broken. But if I change the value of Dimension1 of the last row, the value of the earlier changed row Dimension2 changes - as if the reference for that is now connected to the last row.

I am pretty sure the problem is the *self* in the loop in the view model - and the context it exists in - but I cannot get my head around the solution.

Any help? :-)

View:

```
<section>
    <h2 data-bind="html:displayName"></h2>

    <table class="table">
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: creditCardLines">
            <tr>
                <td class="date" data-bind="text: Date"></td>
                <td class="date" data-bind="text: DocumentNo"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
                <td><select data-bind="options: $parent.dimension1List, optionsText: 'DimensionValue', optionsValue: 'DimensionKey', value: Dimension1Key"></select></td>
                <td><select data-bind="options: dimension2List, optionsText: 'DimensionValue', optionsValue: 'DimensionKey', value: Dimension2Key"></select> </td>
                <td data-bind="text: Currency"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: CurrencyAmount"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: ExchangeRate"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: AmountLCY"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Comment"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: ApprovedEmployee"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</section>
```

ViewModel:

```
define(function (require) {

var submit = function () {
    this.displayName = 'Rejseafregning';

    this.creditCardLines = ko.observableArray();

    var me = this;

    this.activate = function () {
        return $.when(
                $.get('/submit/GetCreditCardLines'),
                $.get('/submit/GetDimensionMatrix')
                )
            .then(function (creditCardLines, dimension1List) {
                me.dimension1List = dimension1List[0].Data;

                for (var i = 0; i < creditCardLines[0].Data.length; i++) {
                    var self = creditCardLines[0].Data[i];

                    self.Dimension1Key = ko.observable(creditCardLines[0].Data[i].Dimension1Key);
                    self.Dimension2Key = ko.observable(creditCardLines[0].Data[i].Dimension2Key);


                    self.dimension2List = ko.computed(function () {
                        for (var j = 0; j < me.dimension1List.length; j++) {
                            if (me.dimension1List[j].DimensionKey === self.Dimension1Key()) {
                                return me.dimension1List[j].DimensionNext;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    me.creditCardLines.push(self);
                }
            });
        };
    };
    return submit;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a `ko.computed` you can pass in a second argument that controls the value of `this` when the computed is evaluated.

When you create your `dimension2List` computed, you would want to pass your current `self` in as the second argument, and then use `this` in the method like:

```
            self.dimension2List = ko.computed(function () {
                for (var j = 0; j < me.dimension1List.length; j++) {
                    if (me.dimension1List[j].DimensionKey === this.Dimension1Key()) {
                        return me.dimension1List[j].DimensionNext;
                    }
                }
            }, self);
```

Otherwise, the value of `self` when the computeds are re-evaluated ends up being the last value that `self` was set to (the last row) based on the way that closures work in JS.

Using the second argument to the `computed` ensures that that specific value will be used as the context.

Comment: Thank you so much - it was context - but not the one I suspected :-)